# Convert to number and to char in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the following code which is working fine:

```
(
(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMdd'),'00000000')=>PMFDAT and to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMdd'),'00000000') <= PMTDAT)
OR
to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMdd'),'00000000') <= PMFDAT
 )
```

but it's not working in SQL Server, this is the error below:

> 'to_char' is not a recognized built-in function name.

So I need to convert this following to SQL Server.

Comment: Use `CAST` or `CONVERT` in `SQL Server`.

Comment: `=>` isn't an operator in T-SQL; it's `>=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code instead of:  *to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMdd'),'00000000')*

```
convert(int,convert(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112))
```

Comment: thank you is working but Invalid column name 'sysdate'.

Comment: can i change it by SYSDATETIME

Comment: Use GETDATE() in SQL Server, refer the edited answer